# Is there a documentation of the Jetstream Componentes used in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I would like to know more about the Jetstream components that come with Laravel 8. I have not found any documentation about this. Do you know any list of component attributes or something?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/stacks/livewire.html#components) can help.

Comment: Thanks, @MathiasHillmann. But, I'm looking for a documentation that shows all the components and their properties ... unfortunately I can't find anything similar to the Jetstream components. But I appreciate the link you sent me, as it is a good Liveware documentation,